# gulp-webpack error: Entry module not found: Error: cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, webpack, gulp-watch

When I try gulp scipts, it throws me the following error

ERROR in Entry module not found:

> Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/milan/Local
>   Sites/project-university/app/public/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/js/scripts.js'
>   in 'C:\Users\milan\Local Sites\project-university\app\public'

below is my **webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App:   settings.themeLocation + "js/scripts.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "scripts-bundled.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  mode: 'development'
}
```

and my **settings.js** :

```js
exports.urlToPreview = 'http://project-university.local/';


exports.themeLocation = 

'C:/Users/milan/Local Sites/project-university/app/public/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
```

Below is my file directory,

Project---- app------ public----------(wordpress content files)

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this error? I'm stuck in this now for the same course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the compiling path defined in `settings.js`. Change the defined path from

```
exports.themeLocation = './public/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
```

to

```
exports.themeLocation = './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
```